# Finding if a cell values (delimited by comma) are all existing in a defined table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here is a sample of the report I have:

[image: pic1]

Basically the report consists in a huge list of suppliers where among other things, I need to identify which of them have all entities (content groups) for the same country, while ignoring the "integrate" tag. Entities for each country are defined in a table separately (right).

So far I tried a combination of =SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH())) but always getting partially what I want.

In column C, in need:

- to display YES if the supplier on that row has all entities for the mentioned country code;
- to display NO otherwise;

My logic on this:

The formula/s needs to pick the country code from 1st table, then look into the 2nd table where entities are defined and check if all the entities in the content group are matching, ignoring "integrate" which is a default tag applied everywhere.

Expected result:

[image: Pic2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowA As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim CountryCode As String
    Dim rng As Range, SearchRange As Range, FindPosition As Range
    Dim Appears As Boolean

    'Set worksheets on variables
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    'Set the range to search in for country codes
    Set SearchRange = ws2.Range("H1:R1")

    With ws1

        'Find the last row of Column A sheet1
        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Start loop from row 2 to last row sheet1
        For i = 2 To LastRowA

            'Criteria needed ( Column A - Not empty cell, Column D - Includes "Europe" & Column E - Includes "No" Columns D and E are CASE SENSITIVE)
            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("D" & i).Value = "Europe" And .Range("E" & i).Value = "No" Then

                CountryCode = .Range("B" & i).Value

                'In which column the country code found
                Set FindPosition = SearchRange.Find(What:=CountryCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

                'If code excist
                If Not FindPosition Is Nothing Then

                    'Set the range to search for the groups in the column where the code is header
                    Set rng = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, FindPosition.Column), ws2.Cells(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, FindPosition.Column).End(xlUp).Row, FindPosition.Column))

                    'Split the string with comma and assing it on arr
                    arr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value)

                    Appears = False

                    'Loop the arr
                    For y = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                        'Check if the arr(y) start from C as all code start from C
                        If Left(arr(y), 1) = "C" Then

                            'Count how many times the arr(y) with out the comma appears in the rng
                            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Replace(arr(y), ",", "")) > 0 Then
                                'If appears the variable Appears is true
                                Appears = True
                            Else
                                'If does not appear the variable Appears is False & Exit the loop
                                Appears = False
                                Exit For
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next y

                    'Check Appears variable status and import value in Column C
                    If Appears = True Then
                        .Range("C" & i).Value = "Yes"
                    Else
                        .Range("C" & i).Value = "No"
                    End If

                'If code does not excist
                Else: MsgBox "Country Code not does not excist."

                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This seems to work for the example given. However, for blank rows it will put a "Yes" (see here: https://i.imgur.com/e3YYhoR.jpg). Also a few things I'd like to ask:
1. How would I update the code if the table with data (the blue one) is situated in another sheet? Let's say Sheet2, range: H1:R20 (first row = country codes)
2. It is possible to run the code if it meets 2 criteria first? 
   a). column D called Region with criteria "Europe".
   b). column E called Registered with criteria "No".
The sheet has 150k lines, so I'd run only for those who meet criteria.

Comment: I managed to do a couple of tests and the code works good. Thank you very much for your time. PS: I commented the line `Else: MsgBox "Country Code not does not excist."` since I would have to click the box a few thousand times; I hope it doesn't affect the way it runs.

Comment: You can comment out that line. I use it for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of Excel 2013+  which has the `FILTERXML` function, you can use this array formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNA(MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Integrate",""),", ",","),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),INDIRECT("Table2["&B2&"]"),0))),"No","Yes")
```

- We remove the `Integrate`
- Create an `XML`from the strings in Table1
- Extract each element of the `XML`
- Try to find them in the appropriate column of Table2
- If we don't find one, then it has multiple countries.

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

If you have a version of Excel that does not have this function, and you are still interested in using excel formulas as opposed to VBA, there is another formula we can use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ron! This works fine, however, the master sheet contains codes for all countries, where my defined table has only 11 countries in total. We skip the rest for now. So my question is: Is it possible to make it display Yes or No only for the country codes from the table header? Also, as I commented to Error's reply, I would like to apply this only to rows where there's other 2 criteria met: column D called Region with criteria "Europe" and column E called Registered with criteria "No". PS: I copied the formula from your picture as the code slider didn't take it fully ^^

Comment: @Jugger Sorry about the incomplete code.  I've corrected that.  So far as the other criteria, you could add some tests for those requirements to the formula provided; or you could merely set up a filter and filter out the rows you don't want to see (those rows not containing the specified values).

Comment: Thank you for your time Ron, your way works fine as well and I did manage to make it follow the other criteria, but I'll stick with the VBA as I have quite a few formulas in that workbook, it's getting slower than it should be.